# Finding transformation function for a distribution that looks like exponential

Tags: matlab, transformation

Suppose that we have two data sets, `R` and `P`. `R` is larger than or equal to `P`. `R` can be negative or positive. `P` can be negative or positive. So in all cases `(R-P)` is positive or zero. the `R` and `P` are dollars and the scale of them is high likes `1,000,000,0` or `500,000,000`. Now I want create a criterion looks like :

```
E = 1 - ( 1 / 1+(R-P) )
```

So I have E that is between `0` and `1`. I want E scale between `0` and `1`. But the problem is this. `(R-P)` is has high values,so all outputs of this criterion is near 1. I revise this function, Now i have this :

```
E = 1 - ( 1 / 1+ ( (R-P)/mean(R-P) ) )
```

Now because of `mean(R-P)` we have better scaling between `0` and `1`. This is distribution of `R-P` for more help :

[image]

After doing that I want classify data with this `E` . For example samples that have a `E` greater than `0.7` are in `class 1` and samples with `E` lower than `0.7` are in `class 2` (In a binary classification problem). For a better distribution in final version of this criterion i will remove outliers of `(R-P)` with this function to have more robust criterion :

```
abs(X-mean(X)) >=2*std(X)

(X here is (R-P)
```

After removing outliers in `R-P` i will calculate `mean(R-P)`. What is your recommendations for better transformation of this problem? I have a theoretical problem with using `mean` in this criterion so i need comments about this.

Thanks.

**Ps**. We have a situation here:

We should have this behavior in this criterion:

- if `P=constant` and `R=increase` >> `E=increase`
- if `R=constant` and `P=increase (towards negative)` >> `E=increase`
- if `P=constant` and `R=decrease` >> `E=decrease`
- if `R=constant` and `P=decrease(towards positive)` >> `E=decrease`
- a sample that have highest `(R-P)` should have highest `E` (`1` or near `1`)
- a sample that have lowest `(R-P)` should have lowest `E` (`1` or near `1`)

Comment: You can use $u=\frac{R-P}{|R|+|P|}$. Because $0\le u \le 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some information to main question.